# C-Linux-Stack smashing detected! for validating input with while loop

Tags: c, linux, validation, gcc, input

```
int test()
{
    char choice[2];
    int score = 0;
    puts("\nPlease ONLY answer with Y or N.\nQ1. (Y or N) ");
    scanf("%s", choice);
    while (strcmp(choice, "Y") && strcmp(choice, "y") && strcmp(choice, "n") && strcmp(choice, "N"))
    {
        printf("\nEnter valid Input(Y or N) : ");
        scanf("%s", choice);
    }
    if (!strcmp(choice, "Y") || !strcmp(choice, "y"))
        score += 30;
    puts("Q2. (Y or N) ");
    scanf("%s", choice);
    while (strcmp(choice, "Y") && strcmp(choice, "y") && strcmp(choice, "n") && strcmp(choice, "N"))
    {
        printf("\nEnter valid Input(Y or N) : ");
        scanf("%s", choice);
    }
    if (!strcmp(choice, "Y") || !strcmp(choice, "y"))
        score += 20;
    puts("Q3. (Y or N) ");
    scanf("%s", choice);
    if (!strcmp(choice, "Y") || !strcmp(choice, "y"))
        score += 20;
    return score;
}
```

> When I call this, if the user only enters y Y n N, the code works allright but if the user enters anything else even once, at the end of the questions, i get `stack smashing error detected`, how can I fix this??

Comment: Do you mean: more than a 1-character string? Code like this is pretty much guaranteed to fail. Please use `scanf("%1s", choice);` to prevent accidental or deliberate buffer overflow.

Comment: ...and better, use `char choice[10];` and `scanf("%9s", choice);` so that if the user accidentally types `YUU` that won't mess up the next two inputs as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char choice[2]; scanf("%s", choice);` is a disaster waiting to happen.

The input buffer `choice` is only 2 characters, so the string can hold only 1 character.
But the `scanf` is allowed to put an arbitrary number of chars at that location.
So if the user enters more than 1 character before hitting enter, those extra chars gets stored in memory not intended to store them. So it overwrites memory belonging to other data, in this case your stack frame. That is detected by the stack smashing detector. In general you could overwrite anything, which is always bad.

Always make sure you stay within the limits of your variable. So force `scanf`to ignore all but the first character by using the format string `%1s`.

Comment: Thanks, I made the choice strings length 10, and compared the first character with y or n, But i suppose @MEDLDN s way is better

Comment: Extending the length of the `choice` buffer doesn't do anything. Limiting the input size in `scanf` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char choice;
    int score = 0;
    puts("Q1. (Y or N) ");

   do
   {
        printf("\nEnter valid Input(Y or N) : ");
        scanf(" %c",&choice);
   }while (choice!='y'&&choice!='Y'&&choice!='n'&&choice!='N');

   if(choice=='y'||choice=='Y')
   {
       score += 30;
   }

   puts("Q2. (Y or N) ");

   do
   {
        printf("\nEnter valid Input(Y or N) : ");
        scanf(" %c",&choice);
   }while (choice!='y'&&choice!='Y'&&choice!='n'&&choice!='N');

   if(choice=='y'||choice=='Y')
   {
        score += 20;
   }

   puts("Q3. (Y or N) ");

   do
   {
        printf("\nEnter valid Input(Y or N) : ");
        scanf(" %c",&choice);
   }while (choice!='y'&&choice!='Y'&&choice!='n'&&choice!='N');

   if(choice=='y'||choice=='Y')
   {
       score += 20;
   }

   printf("\n%d\n",score);

}
```